# Accessing app VCL from a DLL

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dll, vcl

My problem is: I have a VCL Forms Application, and a DLL that contains an implementation of `TThread`. Within this Thread, I have some methods that needs to work with some of the VCL components from the main form, but I now that `TThread.Synchronize()` doesn't work inside the DLL, because it's given another ThreadID to it, and to solve that, I've create a method inside the DLL that receives the MainThreadID from the VCL Application, and set the given it as its own DLL ID, however, it also doesn't work. Can someone point me what I'm doing wrong?

By the way, I tried using a time with interval=1 to `CheckSynchronize()` but it was a dead end whatsoever.

---> Here are relevant parts of the code:

**VCL unit**

```
procedure TfrmUpdater.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
begin
  DllHandle := LoadLibrary('libthread.dll');
  tmrSync.Enabled := True;

  if DllHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @DllThreadProc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'SetDllThread');
    @ConfigProc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'Config');
    @VclProc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'VCL');
    @UpdateProc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'Update');
  end;

  DllThreadProc(MainThreadID);

  // Set the VCL Components to use as reference inside the DLL
  VclProc(btnStartGame, pbCurrent, pbOverall, lblCurrent, lblPercent);
end;
```

**DLL Code**

```
// This, doesn't update the CLbl that has been set as lblCurrent
// Note: this method is called INSIDE the DLL, and has to be like this!
procedure TUpdateThread.UpdateStatusLabel;
begin
  CLbl.Caption := STemp;

  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

// The code below are SOME of the functions that the DLL is exporting to my application
procedure SetDllThread(TID: Cardinal); export;
 begin
   MainThreadID := TID;
 end;

 procedure VCL(playBtn: TImage; currentPBar, totalPBar: TALProgressBar; CurrLbl, ProgressLbl: TLabel); export;
 begin
   Btn := playBtn;
   CBar := currentPBar;
   TBar := totalPBar;
   CLbl := CurrLbl;
   TLbl := ProgressLbl;
 end;
```

Comment: if you want to work with objects - use BPL not DLL. When you work with DLL you demand that no Delphi-specific datatypes exist on the DLL-> | <-EXE boundary. There are two different types now, `TObject` in EXE and another `TObject` in DLL. They only exist within EXE and DLL. They do not exist on EXE/DLL meeting point. Same with all objects derived from those, including `TThread` and `TForm`: EXE and DLLs have different classes for those and they can not interact.  So, again, use standard intended method to exchange Delphi objects, which is BPL (runtime packages)

Comment: Hmm I see. thx for tip! I switch to BPL rather than DLL then. Once again, thanks.

Comment: you would have to switch EXE to "use runtime packages" too, those rtl123.bpl, vcl123.bpl and others, like Delphi IDE itself is constructed.  DLL is cross-language modules, it is for when you write plugins in other non-Delphi languages. And those other languages obviously know nothing about Delphi-specific types like sets, strings, etc. So if you make ALL modules in Delphi and do not need cross-language flexibility, then just use Delphi-native means: BPL.

Comment: Why that library `needs to work with some of the VCL components`? Working code from DLL should be **separated** from any interface. Look at MVC paradigm - it helps to create more robust applications. If it wants to tell something to user, it just sends data packet with minimum of information, and main VCL code treats and shows this info.

Comment: @Miranda: Just FYI: [this article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html) is about using/writing DLLs and the dos and don'ts.

Comment: The issue of using `TThread.Synchronize()` (and `TThread.Queue()`) in a DLL has nothing to do with thread IDs. It has to do with the fact that when the EXE and DLL do not link to the RTL's main runtime package dynamically, the EXE and DLL will be using separate sync queues in memory. The EXE would not see the DLL's requests, and vice versa. To work around that, the DLL would need to export a function that calls the DLL's version of `CheckSynchronize()`, and then the EXE can call that function periodically, such as in a timer or `OnIdle` event handler